# Completions in special .json files?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, code-completion, languageservice

What is the completion support in special files like launch.json powered by in VS Code? Is it only the JSON schema, or is there a more complex completion service behind it? I'm particularly interested in completions like the one below (I did not see `$` or `{` listed as JSON trigger characters...):

[image: launch.json example]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you reword it to describe more precisely what you are after? Is about how such a completion provider is implemented?

Comment: @MikeLischke I'm sorry for not being clearer. My question is if this completion is only powered by the JSON schema (and hence any editor offering JSON IntelliSense based on its schema would offer the completions), or if there's a VS Code specific completion service for these completions inside strings.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.